# Unison: sync only in one direction

Tags: synchronization, unison

If I have folder A and B, is it possible to sync the new files from A to B and to not erase in B files erased in A?

That is to say, I would like to use B as a big container for any file, including the one that I once synchronized from A and than erased. I think is considered kind of "one way syncing".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I understand that you are having these two requirements on Unison

- mirroring folder A to B and
- preserving data on B

**Mirroring**

According to the Unison [manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#prefs), the `-force xxx` option "effectively changes Unison from a synchronizer into a mirroring utility". The `force` option takes the folder that is to be favored as argument. Unison will resolve all changes in favor of this folder.

The commandline to mirror, e.g.,  folder `/src/dir`  to `/dest/dir` would be

```
unison /src/dir /dest/dir -force /src/dir
```

**Preserving**

Use the option `-nodeletion xxx` to prevent Unison from recommending any deletion on the folder `xxx` as default action.

The commandline to preserve files on `/dest/dir` after they have been deleted from `/src/dir` would be

```
unison /src/dir /dest/dir -nodeletion /dest/dir
```

**Sum up**

So in total you want to run Unison with these two options to satisfy your requirements:

```
unison /src/dir /dest/dir -force /src/dir -nodeletion /dest/dir
```

**Notes**

Until you have set up Unison to run in batch mode, I recommend to run Unison in interactive mode using the graphical UI. Working with the graphical UI is more convenient as you see all pending changes including the default actions Unison suggests.

When you are satisfied with the default actions, you can run unison in batch mode (option `-batch`) using the textual UI. In batch mode, changes with default actions will accepted, changes without default action (due to conflicts) will be skipped.

Remember, these options can be overridden in interactive mode by the user. They are in no way an absolute protection against deletion, they just provide guidance to Unison about how to decide on the default action. In interactive mode, the user can always override the default action, i.e., press "<" to propagate the change to the source folder (the direction which you do not want).

Comment: The manual says: `Including the preference -force root causes Unison to resolve all differences (even non-conflicting changes) in favor of root`. So why bother to use `-nodeletion`?

Comment: @TomHale Because without it, the conflict "a file exists in `/dest/dir` but not in `/src/dir`" would also be resolved in favor of `/src/dir` (which means "`/src/dir` is correct"), effectifely deleting it in `/dest/dir`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you probably want to use `noupdate` and/or `nodeletion` options:

 `-nodeletion xxx    prevent file deletions on one replica
 -noupdate xxx      prevent file updates and deletions on one replica`

Read the full description in the [manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#prefs).

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

```
source=A
target=B
unison $source $target -batch -nocreation $source -noupdate $source -force $source
```

Comment: I suggest to try the above command first without the flag `-batch` so you can see what unison is about to do BEFORE it actually does it.

Comment: *Note:* Contrary to the requirements set forth in the question ("to not erase in B files erased in A"), this answer *does* propagate deletions to the destination. Sorry, I upvoted this answer before I tried this exact setup myself. And it seems that I cannot remove my upvote. My bad. To make good, I provided my own answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else came here looking for an actual answer on how to do this with unison you simply need to use the `-force` flag followed with the source directory e.g.

```
unison /source/dir /destination/dir -force /source/dir
```

This will ensure that the destination will match the source no matter what changes are made to the destination.

BTW, `unison` is way faster than `rsync` when you have very large amounts of data spread across millions of files when only a few of which have changed.

Comment: The correct command line has to be `unison  /source/dir /destination/dir -force /source/dir` Sorry lads, I also edited this answer to correct this mistake in it and upvoted it after my correction. However, my edit has been rejected. So this wrong answer stands uncorrected (and I can not downvote it).

Answer (score -4):

Yeah, don't use unison. Just use `rsync`. If you'd like to get fancy, you can use `cron` to schedule when`rsync` gets run, or use`inotify-tools` to watch for changes in folder A and sync exactly when changes happen.

Comment: Honestly, I don't get why you got so many downvotes for this answer. My first reaction when I read the question was also "rsync" :) Esp. since not propagating deletions is the default there!

Comment: The thing that unison really does better is that it automatically detects moves, even across different directories! So if your use case is frequent re-organization of files, then unison gives you a huge decrease in network transfer. The "price" for that is that unison needs a (small) database to make move-detection efficient. So the tools have different pro's and con's.