# Unison: sync only in one direction ...option selected in profile

Tags: unison

I'm effectively asking this question:
[Unison: sync only in one direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848271/unison-sync-only-in-one-direction)
but I'd like to apply the accepted answer to a profile script.  Can I do that?

```
unison /src/dir /dest/dir -force /src/dir -nodeletion /dest/dir
```

Cheers!

Comment: I'm going to ask the obvious question here: why not use rsync simply? Also, what do you mean with "profile script"?

Comment: Yeah you can. Just look in the [Unison manual](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#profile) and instead of using the command-line options `-force` and `-nodeletion` use the corresponding commands in your profile.

Comment: I can't speak for the OP, but in my case, the reason not to use rsync is that the source is a Windows machine, and running rsync on Windows is more trouble than Unison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course you can write that command line to the profile script.

1. Locate the corresponding .prf unison preferences/profile file (usually under $HOME/.unison, but please double check, this may vary depending on your OS or Unison installation)
2. Edit the .prf file and add the following:

```
    # Unison preferences
    label = Sync in only one direction (mirror)
    root = /src/dir
    root = /dest/dir
    force = /src/dir        # force changes from this replica to the other
    nodeletion = /dest/dir  # prevent file deletions on this replica
    noupdate = /src/dir     # prevent file updates on this replica
```

You can also replace step #1 above by creating a new preferences profile using the Profile Editor in the GUI, or your text editor of choice. Please remember the name and location of this file (e.g. $HOME/.unison/sync-one-direction.prf). Then you can call unison from the command line like this:

```
unison $HOME/.unison/sync-one-direction.prf
```

or

```
unison -i
```

The latter will start an interactive profile selection.

HTH